# A pair of dice is rolled. Given that the sum of the dice was even, what is the probability that the sum of the dice was more than 8?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

A pair of dice is rolled. Given that the sum of the dice was even, what is the probability that the sum of the dice was more than 8?

My answer so far is that:
P(E) = |E| / |S|

E=  {all even possibilities}
E = { 11, 13, 15, 22, 24, 26, 31, 33, 35, 42, 44, 46, 51, 53, 55, 62, 64, 66}

18 total even possibilities & 4 that have a sum greater than 8.

P(E) = 4 / 18

Is this correct? Is there a better way to solve?

Thank you

Comment: It´s correct. I don´t know better way of solving

Comment: You have defined the event $E$ to mean "sum is even." You want to let $G$ be the event "greater than $8$." Then you are asked for the conditional probability $\Pr(G\mid E)$. This is indeed $\frac{4}{18}$. You called it $\Pr(E)$ which is notationally wrong. Apart from wrong notation, your solution is correct. It would probably have been a good idea to mention that the $18$ possibilities in your list are all equally likely. Soon you will learn other ways to solve this kind of conditional probability problem. For this problem, they would not be any easier.

Comment: Let $S$ denote the sum, then $P(S>8|S\equiv0\pmod2)=\dfrac{P([S>8]\cap[S\equiv0\pmod2)]}{P(S\equiv0\pmod2))}=\dfrac{4}{18}$.